# Stripe Payment Gateway Exception,while paying to created customer in Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, asp.net-core-webapi

Stripe.StripeException: 
'The address on the customer is invalid. Non INR charges require a name & an address outside India'   in .net core 3.0, while payment to customer in stripe.Error coming at line

```
Charge charge = chargeService.Create(chargeOptions);
```

Following are the code:

```
public ResponseModel StripeCreateCustomer()
        {
            ResponseModel res = new ResponseModel();

                StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = _paymentSettings.Value.SecretKey;

                // Create a Customer:
                var customerOptions = new CustomerCreateOptions
                {
                    Source = "tok_mastercard",//SourceToken
                    Email = "BillReleford@example.com",
                    Name = "JOHN2 SMITH",

                };
                var customerService = new CustomerService();
                Customer customer = customerService.Create(customerOptions);



                // Charge the Customer instead of the card
                var chargeOptions = new ChargeCreateOptions
                {

                    Amount = 1000,
                    Currency = "usd",
                    Customer = customer.Id,
                    Description = "Testing Payment",

                };
                var chargeService = new ChargeService();
                Charge charge = chargeService.Create(chargeOptions);


                res.Message = charge.Status;
                res = returnResultModel(res.Message, (int)HttpStatusCode.OK, true, 0, string.Empty);


            return res;

        }
```

Comment: All I see you doing there, is create a customer based on three values Source, Email and Name - don’t see you creating / setting an address anywhere.

Comment: "StripeConfiguration.ApiKey"  contains a copied stripe secret key, which creates and pay customer respectively using "customerService.Create(customerOptions)" and  "chargeService.Create(chargeOptions);"

Comment: An API key itself does not create anything. And in your customer options, there isn’t an address specified anywhere.

Comment: i put name and address over there, but error was still there

Comment: Edit your question please to show what you actually tried then.

Comment: Thanks 04FS, for your effort, i got the solution

Answer (score 0):

I just got a solution...In stripe account , the country selected was "India" ,when i changed it to "USA" ,it worked.